# Should the source code be hidden for an application.I am testing an application and I am able to view its source code.Should I raise this as a bug

Tags: manual-testing, source-control

Should the source code be hidden for an application.
I am testing an application and I am able to view its source code.Should I raise this as a bug.

Comment: Where can you view it source-code?

Comment: This screams to be of a broken workplace.  Can't you just ask a developer, PM, etc, whether they think this is an issue or not, consider why you think it might be an issue, and reach some reasonable conclusion?

Answer (score 1):

If is is HTML or Javascript it is not usually a problem.  Browsers need to be able to read this in order to display the HTML content and use the javascript and thus so can you.

Note that programmers will sometimes minimize and compress javascript code, often for speed reasons (code can be a lot smaller) and sometimes for obfuscation reasons (intent of code becomes harder / takes longer to understand)
So:

```
# pseudo code
my_policy="abc"
my_driver='bob"
my_policy.driver = my_driver
```

becomes:

```
# pseudo code
a='abc';b='bob';a.d=a;
```

as you can see it is much harder to read and understand the intent!

For non-web stuff where you don't have a client (like a web browser) that needs to read and understand source files then yes, you would want to hide source code and in many applications you can because you are using a compiled language such as Java or C# which ends up with a separate executable for use and deployment.  It can be harder for languages like Python and Ruby where the compiling/parsing is done at runtime (and many people aren't even aware of the step).